# Methods to deal with edge and corner cases of a 3D array

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a fixed size 3D array of floats, and a algorithm that needs to check the value of each array cell and that cell's 7 immediate neighbors in the positive x, y, and z directions. The following piece of code works for the body cases, but it doesn't evaluate the final cells in the edge cases when x, y, or z is equal to Size - 1 because they may not have a neighbor in certain a direction.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

const size_t SIZE     = 10;
const float THRESHOLD = 0.0f;

float array[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE];

int main() {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < SIZE - 1; x++)
    for (size_t y = 0; y < SIZE - 1; y++)
    for (size_t z = 0; z < SIZE - 1; z++) {
        uint8_t mask = 0x00;

        if (array[x    ][y    ][z    ] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x01; }
        if (array[x + 1][y    ][z    ] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x02; }
        if (array[x    ][y + 1][z    ] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x04; }
        if (array[x + 1][y + 1][z    ] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x08; }
        if (array[x    ][y    ][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x10; }
        if (array[x + 1][y    ][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x20; }
        if (array[x    ][y + 1][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x40; }
        if (array[x + 1][y + 1][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) { mask |= 0x80; }

        std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << " mask: " << (int)mask << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My quick solution was wrap the checks that need to accesses a neighbor in a certain direction with if statements to see if that direction was on the edge. If a cell doesn't have a neighbor the evaluation should be equivalent to it being under the threshold.

```
int main() {
    //no longer SIZE - 1, checks all cells now
    for (size_t x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    for (size_t y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
    for (size_t z = 0; z < SIZE; z++) {
        uint8_t mask = 0x00;

        if (array[x][y][z] > THRESHOLD) {
            mask |= 0x01;
        }

        if (x != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x + 1][y][z] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x02;
            }
        }

        if (y != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x][y + 1][z] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x04;
            }
        }

        if (x != SIZE - 1 && y != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x + 1][y + 1][z] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x08;
            }
        }

        if (z != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x][y][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x10;
            }
        }

        if (x != SIZE - 1 && z != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x + 1][y][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x20;
            }
        }

        if (y != SIZE - 1 && z != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x][y + 1][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x40;
            }
        }

        if (x != SIZE - 1 && y != SIZE - 1 && z != SIZE - 1) {
            if (array[x + 1][y + 1][z + 1] > THRESHOLD) {
                mask |= 0x80;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << " mask: " << (int)mask << std::endl;

    }
}
```

This doesn't seem like the best solution for this problem. I'd prefer to write this without the edge guards, is there a way too? I assume there's a way to write loops specifically for each edge and corner and check the neighbors you know that cell has but I'm having trouble finding material about it.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is not a significantly more clever way to do this. This problem frequently appears in all kinds of image processing, but you usually have to allow for different kinds of border handling there ("*is the border undefined/zero/mirrored/repeated/identical to the closest pixel/etc.?*").

A common approach there is to work on array that was enlarged by 1 in each direction (so +2 in each dimension) with border values set correctly. You're then guaranteed to not go out of the array bounds (if you get the loop indices right), but you have to allocate a new array first.

Depending on how often you will have to do this kind of interaction, it might alternatively be useful to write a function that returns an array of seven neighbor values given the coordinates of the center pixel and does the correct border handling (e.g. NaN for voxels outside your array):

```
std::array<float, 7> getVoxelAndNeighbors(int x, int y, int z)
```

This makes your code the most readable in the end, but the performance aspect may suffer a bit because you have to do border checks for each element, even if only very few actually need it.

Another possibility may be to handle the surfaces (and edges (and corners)) separately from the "common" loop body:

```
for (z = 1; z < SIZE-1; ++z)
  for (y = 1; y < SIZE-1; ++y)
    for (x = 1; x < SIZE-1; ++x)
      { /* Your original body */ }

for (y = 1; y < SIZE-1; ++y)
  for (x = 1; x < SIZE-1; ++x)
    { /* Handle positive and negative z surface */ }

// (Repeat for x, y)

for (x = 1; x < SIZE-1; ++x)
  { /* Handle edges in x direction */ }

// (Repeat for x, y)

// Handle all eight corners.
```

This is better for performance in regards to branch mispredictions (no `if`s in the loop body) but it is even more verbose to write and much worse in terms of cache coherence.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible approaches:

1. Just add a test and branch to every op, as you have.

   Equivalently, you can wrap the array in a class with an accessor which performs the test for you, and returns some safe false value for out-of-bound elements.

   Either way you have a lot of branching going on, but the encapsulated version will *look* more like your original code, while behaving exactly like the second version.
2. Add sentinel values into your array.

   That is, enlarge your array to `[SIZE+1][SIZE+1][SIZE+1]` and then store your safe false value in the sentinel entries `array[SIZE][*][*]`, `array[*][SIZE][*]` and `array[*][*][SIZE]`

   The tradeoff is that you no longer need the tests & branches in your code, but your array got bigger and worsened locality of reference.
3. Write out your different cases explicitly.

   You already wrote the `[0..SIZE-2][0..SIZE-2][0..SIZE-2]` case - now write the three remaining cases for `[SIZE-1][0..SIZE-2][0..SIZE-2]`, `[SIZE-1][SIZE-1][0..SIZE-2]` and the isolated far corner `[SIZE-1][SIZE-1][SIZE-1]`.

   This version gives you the smallest data, with the fewest unnecessary branches, but the highest complexity.